# How does implicit Rails rendering work with super in controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the below, will the implicit render still get called in the `SpecialArticlesController`? Or will it get skipped to the implicit render in `ArticlesController`?

```
class SpecialArticlesController < ArticlesController
  def index
    ...
    super
  end
end

class ArticlesController
  def index
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: If `render` is executed in `ArticlesController#index` as part of method chain in your case and if `SpecialArticlesController#index` also executes `render` again then there will be `DoubleRenderError`.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a double render error, unless you are explicitly rendering twice. This code will cause an error:

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render
  end
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  def index
    render
    super
  end
end
```

Whereas the code below will not cause an error:

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  def index
    super
    render
  end
end
```